# Output json file on some fields without filtering data with Shodan?

Tags: shodan

I've downloaded some JSON data from Shodan, and only want to retain some fields from it. To explore what I want, I'm running the following, which works-

```
shodan parse --fields ip,port --separator , "data.json.gz"
```

However, I now want to output/ export the data; I'm trying to run the following -

```
shodan parse --fields ip,port -O "data_processed.json.gz" "data.json.gz"
```

It's requiring me to specify a filter parameter, which I don't need. If I do add an empty filter as so, it tells me data_processes.json.gz doesn't exist.

```
shodan parse --fields ip,port -f -O "data_processed.json.gz" "data.json.gz"
```

I'm a bit stumped on how to export only certain fields of my data; how do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to output those 2 properties then you can simply pipe them to a file:

```sh
shodan parse --fields ip,port --separator , data.json.gz > data_processed.csv
```

A few things to keep in mind:

1. You probably want to export the **ip_str** property as it's a more user-friendly version of the IP address. The **ip** property is a numeric version of the IP address and aimed at users storing the information in a database.
2. You can convert your data file into Excel or CSV format using the `shodan convert` command. For example: `shodan convert data.json.gz csv` See here for a quick guide: https://help.shodan.io/guides/how-to-convert-to-excel

Comment: That worked, thanks! I also appreciate the heads up about the csv- however, I'm losing data on vulnerabilities when I do convert it; but that's probably to do with how the data is inherently stored within the files. My team and I are still playing around with the data, but yeah; thanks once again!

Comment: Make sure you're running the latest version of the CLI as that was a bug we recently fixed (https://github.com/achillean/shodan-python/issues/85). If you export to CSV using the latest version of the library/ CLI you will see the vulnerability information as well. However, you will still lose a few other properties as it's difficult to flatten all the information that's stored in JSON.